# Get row where certain date value occurs

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to persist the last row with yesterday's date.

My data looks like the following:

[image]

I have tried the following to persist the data, which works well.

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Store values');
  Logger.log(ss.getName());

  // get yesterday's date
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(now.getDate()-1);
  yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, "GMT+1", 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  Logger.log("yesterday: " + yesterday);


  var source = ss.getRange('4:4');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('4:4'), {contentsOnly: true});

  source.setFontWeight("bold");
}
```

Find below an example spreadsheet:

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F5jOaBDG6kzj2or8exz5pZdgb9Vw8d_E8QBHYbStHHM/edit?usp=sharing)

As you can see I am getting yesterday's date correctly formatted in my script as in my `Date` column. I also can correctly '*persist*' the data.

My problem is that I do not know how to get the range where yesterday's date occurs so that I can hand it over in my script to persist it.

Any suggestions how to get the row that matches yesterday's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not totally sure what you mean by "persist" but the function below returns the row number for the first row with yesterday's date in it:

```
function getYesterdayRow(yesterdayDate,columnRange) {
    var displayValues = columnRange.getDisplayValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < displayValues.length; i++) {
        var displayValue = displayValues[i][0];
        if (displayValue === yesterdayDate) return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can call it like this in your code after you've defined yesterday:

```
var yesterdayRow = getYesterdayRow(yesterday,ss.getRange(A:A))
```

Note that this function quickly fixes your current need, but it uses `getdisplayValues()`, which is a quick cheat to not have to deal with processing the date. You should probably modify this function so that it would work with other date formats. (Use `getValues()`, get the day, time and month from `yesterday`, then the same from each value in the `for loop`, and make sure to account for any timezone offsets.)